# Chaining / building LINQ query with an OR instead of AND

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

*Edited to be clearer.*

If for example I have this IQueryable:

```
DateTime theDate = new DateTime(2015, 09, 30);

var query = from org in Organisations
            where org.DisableOrganisation == false &&
              org.DisableReports == false
            select new
            {
                OrganisationId = org.OrganisationId
            };
```

and later in the method I want to add an OR to it, e.g.

```
// Check to see if the date is the last day of the month.
if (theDate.AddDays(1).Day == 1)
{
    // The following statement introduces an AND but I want to make this an OR.
    query = query.Where(x => x.Frequency == "M");
}
```

This effectively makes my query...

```
var query = from org in Organisations
            where org.DisableOrganisation == false &&
              org.DisableReports == false &&
              org.Frequency == "M"
            select new
            {
                OrganisationId = org.OrganisationId
            };
```

but I want to make it...

```
var query = from org in Organisations
            where (org.DisableOrganisation == false &&
              org.DisableReports == false) ||
              org.Frequency == "M"
            select new
            {
                OrganisationId = org.OrganisationId
            };
```

How do I go about making this an OR instead of an AND ?

**P.S.** Cannot use PredicateBuilder as it is essentially LinqKit which has a dependency of EntityFramework (≥ 6.0.2), I'm stuck using EF 4.3.1

**SOLVED:** Thanks to D Stanley (To be honest I had used this form of solution before, I simply forgot about it).

```
DateTime theDate = new DateTime(2015, 09, 30);
bool isEndOfMonth = theDate.AddDays(1).Day == 1;

var query = from org in Organisations
            where (org.DisableOrganisation == false &&
              org.DisableReports == false) ||
              (isEndOfMonth &&
               pr.ProfileType == "L" && 
               pr.Frequency == "M")
            select new
            {
                OrganisationId = org.OrganisationId
            };
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ WHERE with OR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136116/linq-where-with-or)

Comment: @TomDoesCode It in essence duplicates that question, but that question is 4 years old... is there a newer solution?

Comment: @TomDoesCode The possible duplicate points to LinqKit... which has a dependency of EntityFramework (≥ 6.0.2), I'm using EF 4.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it by chaining - you'll have to use some sort of expression builder, or just build that in your original filter:

```
var day = theDate.AddDays(1).Day;

var query = from org in Organisations
            where (org.DisableOrganisation == false &&
                   org.DisableReports == false) ||
                  (day == 1 &&
                   org.ProfileType == "L" && 
                   org.Frequency == "M")
            select new
            {
                OrganisationId = org.OrganisationId
            };
```

Answer (score 2):

To combine conditions with OR instead of AND, use the  [PredicateBuilder:](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

```
predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Description.Contains (temp));
return dataContext.Products.Where(predicate);
```

Comment: LinqKit... which has a dependency of EntityFramework (≥ 6.0.2), I'm using EF 4.3.1

Comment: source code is open, maybe it is possible to extract functionality you need. https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit