# Dynamic query with OR conditions in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I am creating an application that searches the database and allows the user to  dynamically add any criteria (around 50 possible), much like the following SO question: [Creating dynamic queries with entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5541234/810850). I currently have working a search that checks each criteria, and if it is not blank it adds it to the query.

**C#**

```
var query = Db.Names.AsQueryable();
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(first))
      query = query.Where(q => q.first.Contains(first));
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(last))
      query = query.Where(q => q.last.Contains(last));
  //.. around 50 additional criteria
  return query.ToList();
```

This code produces something similar to the following in sql server (I simplified for easier understanding)

**SQL**

```
SELECT
    [Id],
    [FirstName],
    [LastName],
    ...etc
FROM [dbo].[Names]
WHERE [FirstName] LIKE '%first%'
  AND [LastName] LIKE '%last%'
```

I am now trying to add a way to generate the following SQL with C# through entity framework but with an **OR** instead of an **AND**, while still keeping the ability to add criteria dynamically.

**SQL**

```
SELECT
    [Id],
    [FirstName],
    [LastName],
    ...etc
  FROM [dbo].[Names]
WHERE [FirstName] LIKE '%first%'
  OR [LastName] LIKE '%last%' <-- NOTICE THE "OR"
```

Usually the criteria wont be larger than two or three items for a query but combining them into one gigantic query is not an option. I have tried concat, union, and intersect and they just all duplicate the query and join them with UNION.

Is there a simple and clean way to add "OR" conditions to a dynamically generated query using entity framework?

**Edit with my solution - 9/29/2015**

Since posting this, I have noticed this has received a little attention, so I decided to post my solution

```
// Make sure to add required nuget
// PM> Install-Package LinqKit

var searchCriteria = new 
{
    FirstName = "sha",
    LastName = "hill",
    Address = string.Empty,
    Dob = (DateTime?)new DateTime(1970, 1, 1),
    MaritalStatus = "S",
    HireDate = (DateTime?)null,
    LoginId = string.Empty,
};

var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Person>();
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchCriteria.FirstName))
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.FirstName.Contains(searchCriteria.FirstName));
}

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchCriteria.LastName))
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.LastName.Contains(searchCriteria.LastName));
}

// Quite a few more conditions...

foreach(var person in this.Persons.Where(predicate.Compile()))
{
    Console.WriteLine("First: {0} Last: {1}", person.FirstName, person.LastName);
}
```

Comment: You may want to look into something like [Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) which makes it easier to do the and's and or's.

Comment: Predicate Builder is really the answer here, but I'm just curious...why is combining them "not an option"? You say it won't be larger than two or three items. SQL Server would likely be able to optimize your large combined query to run at a similar speed to a single one with the same conditions. Have you tested this and found that joining the queries is a performance bottleneck?

Comment: Looking into predicate builder, I believe it is the answer. Thanks Steven V, if you want to submit an answer I will mark it as answered. Combining them into a large query is not an option because I would need to check every criteria inline blank then I would do the actual filtering, and that is over 50 criteria. It would make the query slow and hard to manage.

Comment: An alternative to Predicate Builder is the code in the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677492/build-an-or-query-expression-progressively

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like [Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) which allows you to control the AND's and OR's of the where statement easier.

There's also [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) which allows you to submit the WHERE clause like a SQL string and it will parse it into the correct predicate for a WHERE.

Answer (score 25):

While LINQKit and its PredicateBuilder are fairly versatile, it's possible to do this more directly with a few simple utilities (each of which can serve as the foundation for other Expression-manipulating operations):

First, a general-purpose Expression Replacer:

```
public class ExpressionReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Func<Expression, Expression> replacer;

    public ExpressionReplacer(Func<Expression, Expression> replacer)
    {
        this.replacer = replacer;
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return base.Visit(replacer(node));
    }
}
```

Next, a simple utility method to replace one parameter's usage with another parameter in a given expression:

```
public static T ReplaceParameter<T>(T expr, ParameterExpression toReplace, ParameterExpression replacement)
    where T : Expression
{
    var replacer = new ExpressionReplacer(e => e == toReplace ? replacement : e);
    return (T)replacer.Visit(expr);
}
```

This is necessary because the lambda parameters in two different expressions are actually different parameters, even when they have the same name. For example, if you want to end up with `q => q.first.Contains(first) || q.last.Contains(last)`, then the `q` in `q.last.Contains(last)` must be the *exact same* `q` that's provided at the beginning of the lambda expression.

Next we need a general-purpose `Join` method that's capable of joining `Func<T, TReturn>`-style Lambda Expressions together with a given Binary Expression generator.

```
public static Expression<Func<T, TReturn>> Join<T, TReturn>(Func<Expression, Expression, BinaryExpression> joiner, IReadOnlyCollection<Expression<Func<T, TReturn>>> expressions)
{
    if (!expressions.Any())
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("No expressions were provided");
    }
    var firstExpression = expressions.First();
    var otherExpressions = expressions.Skip(1);
    var firstParameter = firstExpression.Parameters.Single();
    var otherExpressionsWithParameterReplaced = otherExpressions.Select(e => ReplaceParameter(e.Body, e.Parameters.Single(), firstParameter));
    var bodies = new[] { firstExpression.Body }.Concat(otherExpressionsWithParameterReplaced);
    var joinedBodies = bodies.Aggregate(joiner);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TReturn>>(joinedBodies, firstParameter);
}
```

We'll use this with `Expression.Or`, but you could use the same method for a variety of purposes, like combining numeric expressions with `Expression.Add`.

Finally, putting it all together, you can have something like this:

```
var searchCriteria = new List<Expression<Func<Name, bool>>();

  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(first))
      searchCriteria.Add(q => q.first.Contains(first));
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(last))
      searchCriteria.Add(q => q.last.Contains(last));
  //.. around 50 additional criteria
var query = Db.Names.AsQueryable();
if(searchCriteria.Any())
{
    var joinedSearchCriteria = Join(Expression.Or, searchCriteria);
    query = query.Where(joinedSearchCriteria);
}
  return query.ToList();
```

Comment: This is sick! I made a GitHub gist of a working example for it (compiling at least in .NET 5.0) https://gist.github.com/princefishthrower/6620fcded6b2600bbd10f4100c55401c

Comment: My answer baseon yours answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69156702/6859121 . Thanks.

Comment: How can I use this like query.Where(entity => entity.Collection.Any(joinedSearchCriteria)?
How can I build the Expression for the where query? I already tried for hours but didn't find a way to get the Any method info.

Comment: @Snaketec: It should work fine as long as your criteria's generic type matches that of `entity.Collection`. It sounds like maybe you should put together a separate question with details about what you've tried and what behavior/errors you're seeing.

Answer (score 14):

> Is there a simple and clean way to add "OR" conditions to a dynamically generated query using entity framework?

Yes, you can achieve this by simply relying on a single `where` clause containing a single boolean expression whose `OR` parts are "disabled" or "enabled" dynamically at runtime, thus, avoiding having to install LINQKit or writing a custom predicate builder.

In reference to your example:

```
var isFirstValid = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(first);
var isLastValid = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(last);

var query = db.Names
  .AsQueryable()
  .Where(name =>
    (isFirstValid && name.first.Contains(first)) ||
    (isLastValid && name.last.Contains(last))
  )
  .ToList();
```

As you can see in the example above, we are dynamically switching "on" or "off" the OR-parts of the `where`-filter expression based on previously evaluated premises (e.g `isFirstValid`).

For example if `isFirstValid` is not `true`, then `name.first.Contains(first)` is [short-circuited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9344369/2477619) and will neither be executed nor affect the resultset. Moreover, EF Core's `DefaultQuerySqlGenerator` will further [optimize and reduce](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/4498b7dbe5fd7c09527f51be218e4b41c051d5fb/src/EFCore.Relational/Query/Sql/DefaultQuerySqlGenerator.cs#L412) the boolean expression inside `where` before executing it (e.g. `false && x || true && y || false && z` may be reduced to simply `y` through simple static analysis).

Please note: If none of the premises are `true`, then the result-set will be empty – which I assume is the desired behavior in your case. However, if you for some reason rather prefer to select all elements from your `IQueryable` source, then you may add a final variable to the expression evaluating to `true`  (e.g. `.Where( ... || shouldReturnAll)` with `var shouldReturnAll = !(isFirstValid || isLastValid)` or something similar).

A final remark: The downside of this technique is that it forces you to build a "centralized" boolean expression that resides in the same method body in which your query lies (more precisely the `where` part of the query). If you, for some reason, want to decentralize the build process of your predicates and inject them as arguments or chain them via the query builder, then you should better stick with a predicate builder as suggested in the other answers. Otherwise, enjoy this simple technique :)

Comment: I like this for most simple dynamic queries. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, dynamic in the sense that you've got two optional OR statements, but not really dynamic in that you still have to write whatever you need in the Where() function...

Comment: @fullStackChris yup, this is the downside I mentioned in the "disclaimer" at the end of my answer. But often such optional OR statements come quite handy and are "dynamic" enough to solve the problem at hand. However, of course for more complex chaining of query predicates, one would resort to one of the other techniques.

Answer (score 2):

Basedon [StriplingWarrior's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50414456/6859121), I write my linq extension to do this work in linq way:

https://github.com/Flithor/ReusableCodes/blob/main/EFCore/OrPredicate.cs

The codes(may not newest):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Flithors_ReusableCodes
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Make <see cref="IQueryable{T}"/> support or predicate in linq way
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    public interface IQueryOr<T>
    {
        IQueryOr<T> WhereOr(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        IQueryable<T> AsQueryable();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// The extension methods about or predicate
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    public static class OrPredicate
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Private or predicate builder
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        private class OrPredicateBuilder<T> : IQueryOr<T>
        {
            List<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> predicates = new List<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>();
            IQueryable<T> sourceQueryable;

            #region private methods
            internal OrPredicateBuilder(IQueryable<T> sourceQueryable) => this.sourceQueryable = sourceQueryable;
            private OrPredicate(IQueryable<T> sourceQueryable, IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> predicates)
            {
                this.sourceQueryable = sourceQueryable;
                this.predicates.AddRange(predicates);
            }

            //===============================================
            // Code From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50414456/6859121
            private class ExpressionReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
            {
                private readonly Func<Expression, Expression> replacer;

                public ExpressionReplacer(Func<Expression, Expression> replacer)
                {
                    this.replacer = replacer;
                }

                public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
                {
                    return base.Visit(replacer(node));
                }
            }
            private static TExpression ReplaceParameter<TExpression>(TExpression expr, ParameterExpression toReplace, ParameterExpression replacement) where TExpression : Expression
            {
                var replacer = new ExpressionReplacer(e => e == toReplace ? replacement : e);
                return (TExpression)replacer.Visit(expr);
            }
            private static Expression<Func<TEntity, TReturn>> Join<TEntity, TReturn>(Func<Expression, Expression, BinaryExpression> joiner, IReadOnlyCollection<Expression<Func<TEntity, TReturn>>> expressions)
            {
                if (!expressions.Any())
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("No expressions were provided");
                }
                var firstExpression = expressions.First();
                if (expressions.Count == 1)
                {
                    return firstExpression;
                }
                var otherExpressions = expressions.Skip(1);
                var firstParameter = firstExpression.Parameters.Single();
                var otherExpressionsWithParameterReplaced = otherExpressions.Select(e => ReplaceParameter(e.Body, e.Parameters.Single(), firstParameter));
                var bodies = new[] { firstExpression.Body }.Concat(otherExpressionsWithParameterReplaced);
                var joinedBodies = bodies.Aggregate(joiner);
                return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, TReturn>>(joinedBodies, firstParameter);
            }
            //================================================
            private Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetExpression() => Join(Expression.Or, predicates);
            #endregion

            #region public methods
            public IQueryOr<T> WhereOr(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
            {
                return new OrPredicate<T>(sourceQueryable, predicates.Append(predicate));
            }
            public IQueryable<T> AsQueryable()
            {
                if (predicates.Count > 0)
                    return sourceQueryable.Where(GetExpression());
                else // If not any predicates exists, returns orignal query
                    return sourceQueryable;
            }
            #endregion
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Convert <see cref="IQueryable{T}"/> to <see cref="IQueryOr{T}"/> to make next condition append as or predicate.
        /// Call <see cref="IQueryOr{T}.AsQueryable"/> back to <see cref="IQueryable{T}"/> linq.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TSource"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="source"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IQueryOr<TSource> AsWhereOr<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source)
        {
            return new OrPredicateBuilder<TSource>(source);
        }
    }
}
```

How to use it:

```
// IQueryable<ClassA> myQuery = ....;
  
var queryOr = myQuery.AsWhereOr();
// for a condition list ...
// queryOr = queryOr.WhereOr(a => /*some condition*/)

myQuery = queryOr.AsQueryable();
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Interesting approach. Having `WhereOr` change the state and return the same object is an anti-pattern, especially in LINQ syntax. Consider following the pattern used by `OrderBy().ThenBy()`, where the returned interface extends IQueryable, and each returned object is an immutable query.

Comment: Also think carefully about what users would expect when `WhereOr()` never gets called. Should they get an exception? Or the original query without any filters applied?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I fixed issues: return the same object - now it returns new object; throw exception when user never called `WhereOr` - now will returns orignal query.

Comment: You're still changing the original object's `predicates`, though. So calling `queryOr.WhereOr(...)` will change the `queryOr` object even if you don't do an assignment (`queryOr = ...`). Consider using an immutable collection for predicates instead of a list?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior oops, my mistake