# LINQ: Split Where OR conditions

Tags: sql, .net, linq, where-clause, multiple-conditions

So I have the following where conditions

```
sessions = sessions.Where(y => y.session.SESSION_DIVISION.Any(x => x.DIVISION.ToUpper().Contains(SearchContent)) ||
                                                   y.session.ROOM.ToUpper().Contains(SearchContent) ||
                                                   y.session.COURSE.ToUpper().Contains(SearchContent));
```

I want to split this into multiple lines based on whether a string is empty for example:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Division)) {
    sessions = sessions.Where(y => y.session.SESSION_DIVISION.Any(x => x.DIVISION.ToUpper().Contains(SearchContent)));
}

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Room)) {

    // this shoudl be OR
    sessions = sessions.Where(y => y.session.ROOM.ToUpper().Contains(SearchContent));
}

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(course)) {

    // this shoudl be OR
    sessions = sessions.Where(y => y.session.COURSE.ToUpper().Contains(SearchContent));
}
```

If you notice I want to add multiple OR conditions split based on whether the Room, course, and Division strings are empty or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways to go about this:

1. Apply the "where" to the original query each time, and then `Union()` the resulting queries.

   ```
   var queries = new List<IQueryable<Session>>();
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Division)) {
       queries.Add(sessions.Where(y => y.session.SESSION_DIVISION.Any(x => x.DIVISION.ToUpper().Contains(SearchContent))));
   }

   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Room)) {

       // this shoudl be OR
       queries.Add(sessions.Where(y => y.session.ROOM.ToUpper().Contains(SearchContent)));
   }

   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(course)) {

       // this shoudl be OR
       queries.Add(sessions.Where(y => y.session.COURSE.ToUpper().Contains(SearchContent)));
   }

   sessions = queries.Aggregate(sessions.Where(y => false), (q1, q2) => q1.Union(q2));
   ```
2. Do Expression manipulation to merge the bodies of your lambda expressions together, joined by `OrElse` expressions. (Complicated unless you've already got libraries to help you: after joining the bodies, you also have to traverse the expression tree to replace the parameter expressions. It can get sticky. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50414456/120955) for details.
3. Use a tool like [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to do #2 for you.

Answer (score 1):

`.Where()` assumes logical `AND` and as far as I know, there's no out of box solution to do it. If you want to separate `OR` statements, you may want to look into using [Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) or [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method to conditionally apply the filter:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereIf<T>(
   this IQueryable<T> source, bool condition, 
   Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return condition ? source.Where(predicate) : source;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
using static System.String;

...

var res = sessions
   .WhereIf(!IsNullOrEmpty(Division), y => y.session.SESSION_DIVISION.ToUpper().Contains(SearchContent))
   .WhereIf(!IsNullOrEmpty(Room), y => y.session.ROOM.ToUpper().Contains(SearchContent))
   .WhereIf(!IsNullOrEmpty(course), y => y.session.COURSE.ToUpper().Contains(SearchContent)));
```