# EF - Combine multiple OR in WHERE clause in a loop

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a list which contains multiple time frames.
Each time frame is a `timeframe` class instance.

```
public class TimeFrame
{
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    public DateTime To { get; set; }
}
```

I want to filter some entity by `DateTime CreationDateTime` field with WHERE clause using all timeframes in my list combined with OR.

Something like this

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Entities
WHERE 
    ((T1-From <= CreationDateTime) AND (CreationDateTime <= T1-To))
    OR ((T2-From <= CreationDateTime) AND (CreationDateTime <= T2-To))
    OR ((TN-From <= CreationDateTime) AND (CreationDateTime <= TN-To))
```

How can i do it using entity framework version 6?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic query with OR conditions in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054742/dynamic-query-with-or-conditions-in-entity-framework)

Comment: What are `T1`,`T2` and `TN` ? Is `CreationDateTime` variable?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn looks like variable time, which is coming from loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) in [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) you could do something like this:

```
IQueryable<Entity> SearchEntities (List<TimeFrame> times)
{
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Product>();

  foreach (string time in times)
  {
    TimeFrame temp = time;
    predicate = predicate.Or (p => (temp.From <= p.CreationDateTime) AND (p.CreationDateTime <= temp.To));
  }
  return dataContext.Entities.AsExpandable().Where (predicate);
}
```