# Entity Framework Core with multiple Where clause joined by OR operator

Tags: postgresql, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I build a NetCore 3.1 application who use Postgres as database engine, and I have an entity `SomeEntity` who contains:

- Id : *int*
- Name: *text*
- Tags: *text[]*

I try to build a filter on the attribute `Tags`. It must only select rows where the `Tags` array contains one or more elements of an unknown length array argument.

Let's use an example !

We have this `SomeEntity` with the data set bellow:

| Id | Name | Tags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | n1 | array ("tag1", "tag2", "tag3") |
| 2 | n2 | array ("tag2", "tag3") |
| 3 | n2 | array ("tag3") |

I want to get all rows where the attribute Tags contains the value "**Tag1**" or "**Tag2**" *(The `Tags` can contain more than one values at the same time)*.

I've tried the code bellow:

```
List<string> terms = new List<string> { "Tag1", "Tag2" };

IQueryable<FileEntity> query = Context.SomeEntity;

foreach (string term in terms) {
    query = query.Where(w => w.Tags.Contains(term));
}

List< SomeEntity > result = query.ToList();
```

But when you chained the "*where*" statement with linq, it will result to a list of **AND** operator.
This is the SQL request resulting from the above code.

```
SELECT f."Id", f."name", f."Tags"
FROM " SomeEntity " AS f
WHERE ((@__andEl_0 = ANY (f."Tags") AND @__andEl_1 = ANY (f."Tags"));
```

So, how can I build this request with **OR** operator in place of *AND* ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic query with OR conditions in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054742/dynamic-query-with-or-conditions-in-entity-framework)

Comment: Or `PredicateBuilder ` from [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit#predicatebuilder)

Answer (score 0):

As proposed by Guru Stron, I've give a try to [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit#using-predicatebuilder), that I didn't know.

```
The code I searched for hours was waiting for me right here!
IQueryable<Product> SearchProducts (params string[] keywords)
{
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Product>();

  foreach (string keyword in keywords)
  {
    string temp = keyword;
    predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.Description.Contains (temp));
  }
  return dataContext.Products.Where (predicate);
}
```

Thanks a lot! You saved my day.

But it's really strange that we can't do it without an external library.

Comment: There is a lot of missing translation capabilities in EF Core 3.x and greater as they re-wrote to avoid client side processing but have not equaled EF 6.x or LINQ to SQL capabilities, and have little interest in doing so in some cases.