# How to chain alternative conditions in where clause in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to rewrite the following query as a separate statements:

```
var sql = Repository.Products.AsQueryable();

sql = sql.Where(x => x.Name == "aaaaa" || x.Name == "bbbbb");
```

If I do it like this:

```
sql = sql.Where(x => x.Name == "aaaaa");
sql = sql.Where(x => x.Name == "bbbbb");
```

then the resulting query is equal to:

```
sql = sql.Where(x => x.Name == "aaaaa" && x.Name == "bbbbb");
```

Is there any ideas how to do it the right way?

Comment: What is wrong with the original way of doing it?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101540/linq-or-equivalent-of-where and see if it relates to what you want to achieve, since there must be a good reason for wanting to split up the condition.

Comment: I use this in a search filter, which makes it possible for a user to supply variable number of conditions to include in a query. So the number of conditions is unknown in the beginning

Comment: See @GuruStron answer. `Where` predicate only combines in an `And` manner. If you want an `Or` you have to do fancy Expression Tree unwrapping. Use `PredicateBuilder`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The right way... **is that**. I mean, you *could* write it as

```
sql.Where(x => x.Name == "aaaaa").Concat(sql.Where(x => x.Name == "bbbbb"));
```

but that's *slower*, *unordered* **and** looks weirder too. I don't know what you're looking for, because the way that you posted **is** the right way to do it.

**However**, it seems you want to build the expression dynamically (judging from your comment). If so, then you're looking for a `PredicateBuilder`:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<YourType>();
var search = new[] {"aaaaa", "bbbbb"};
foreach (string y in search)
{
    string name = y;
    predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.Name == name);
}
sql = sql.Where(predicate);
```

The code for `PredicateBuilder` is [here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I was looking for. The generated SQL looks like this: `SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Name] IN (N'aaaaa',N'bbbbb')`

Comment: @user2537328: You can have this special SQL more direct without PredicateBuilder: `sql = sql.Where(x => search.Contains(x.Name))`. PredicateBuilder is useful if you have an OR between conditions on *different* properties.

Comment: @Slauma This is (I'm guessing) an example.

Comment: Yes, I think so. I was only refering to the `IN` clause in the comment above. `PredicateBuilder` solves more general conditions of course.

Comment: @Slauma: Interesting point to keep in mind, but in my case I do use different properties (sample in the question is very simplified), so I think using predicates is the best decision so far.

Comment: Old topic, but if you are using EF Core this will fail by default - and legacy / .NET framework EF will execute this on the client rather than on the server, which is why it is disabled by default in EF Core.

Answer (score 4):

if you want to build you predicate based on come conditions use [Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)