# Entity Framework - how to build a query with a list of OR clauses

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

I'm looking for a way to chain multiple OR clauses in a EF query.

Here's an example function, which, when called with an argument `int[]` containing exactly 2 elements, will create an OR clause with them (of course, less than 2 elements would cause an exception and more than 2 elements would be ignored):

```
public async Task<List<MyTable>> MyQuery(DbContext dbContext, int[] list)
{
    IQueryable<MyTable> q = dbContext.MyTable;

    q = q.Where(x => x.Id == list[0] || x.Id == list[1]);

    // here I chain several other clauses...
    q = q.Where(x => x.SomeOtherFiled == 123);

    return  await q.ToListAsync();
}
```

I would like to modify this code in a way that would perform OR logic with all the elements of the array (1-n; ie. any length). In this example I'm using an int data type, but in reality it could be any data type that can exist in a EF data set. Several AND conditions could be chained together (here I use *SomeOtherFiled*  as an example). I hope I explained well the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to chain alternative conditions in where clause in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395417/how-to-chain-alternative-conditions-in-where-clause-in-entity-framework)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic query with OR conditions in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20055137/1260204)

Comment: I took a look at LinqKit, but it seems a pretty complicated subject, and the examples are not very helpful. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you are describing is equivalent to the `IN` operator in SQL (ex: `WHERE Id IN (1,4,6)`).

The equivalent Linq is like this:

```
int[] list = {1,4,6};
q = q.Where(x => list.Contains(x.Id))
```