# EF Core With Dynamic Where and ForEach

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a table with a string/varchar property.

My method accepts a string, which can be a comma separated list.

My goal is to build a dynamic where clause that will loop through the comma separated list and make a where clause with my query but I'm not getting the syntax correct.

```
public async List<DataObj> GetData(string pets)
{
   IQueryable<DataObj> query = dbSet;
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pets))
   {
       var split = pets.Split(",");
       foreach (var t in split)
       {
          query = query.Where(x => x.Pets.Contains(t.Trim()));
       }
    }
    return await query.DataObj.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
}
```

So if DataObj.Pets for one record is "dog, cat". And DataObj.Pets for another record is: "dog, birds".

If I put in "birds" as the argument to the repo, it should return DataObj2, if I put in "dog", it should return both, and if I put in "dog, birds" the query should return both DataObj1 and DataObj2.

Is anything wrong with my query, because it's not doing that.

Comment: _because it's not doing that._ - can you tell what it is doing, did you get some error?

Comment: Your requirements are for `Or` condition, by chaining `Where` expressions you are using `And` condition

Comment: Chained `.Where()` clauses `AND` in entity framework.  Related: [How to chain alternative conditions in where clause in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395417/how-to-chain-alternative-conditions-in-where-clause-in-entity-framework)

Comment: Check [this my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67666993/10646316)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I put in "birds" as the argument to the repo, it should return
> DataObj2, if I put in "dog", it should return both, and if I put in
> "dog, birds" the query should return both DataObj1 and DataObj2.

Your requirements are for `Or` condition, by chaining `Where` expression you are using `And` condition

You can use predicate builder or dynamic LINQ to build multiple `Or` conditions.

Just for fun - you can utilize asynchronous approach

```
public async Task<List<DataObj>> GetData(string pets)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pets)) return new List<DataObj>();

   var tasks = pets.Split(",")
     .Select(p => context.DataObects.Where(o => o.Pets.Contains(p)).ToListAsync())
     .ToArray();

   await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

   return tasks.SelectMany(t => t.Result).ToList();
}
```

Comment: PredicateBuilder is what I'm looking for, thanks!