# How to return a query based on linq when using a task windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-8, collections, windows-phone-8.1

I am new to tasks and I am trying to figure out how to do a query on a list that is returned from aync method usually I would do something like this cause obv linq is not a async method how would one achieve this kinda of secenrio

```
List<MovieDetail> _mySearchDetail = _myMovie.Where(p => p.name == movietitle).ToList();
```

But cause its retunning from a task that wont work my two methods are as follows.

This gets the movie details from the webservice

```
public async Task<List<MovieDetail>> GetMovieDetailsList(int movieId)
{

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<List<MovieDetail>>();
        string jsonresult = await WCFRESTServiceCall("GET", "movie_details");

        var list = await Task.Run(() => jsonresult.Deserialize<MovieDetails>());
        tcs.SetResult(list.movieDetaillist);
        // for testing to show json being returned
        var dialog = new MessageDialog(jsonresult);
        await dialog.ShowAsync();

        return await tcs.Task;
}
```

Then what I was wanting to do was build up a search function to allow me to search movie by name , description , actor and what not.

```
public Task<List<MovieDetail>> searchMovies(string movietitle)
{
        List <MovieDetail> _myMovie = await GetMovieDetailsList(1);
        var list = await Task.Run(() => how do i query above here ???? >());


        List<MovieDetail> _mySearchDetail = _myMovie.Where(p => p.name == movietitle).ToList();

        return await tcs.Task;
}
```

I have included my movieDetail class for completness of code:

```
public class MovieDetail
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
    public string secondry_images { get; set; }
    public string actor { get; set; }
    public string actoress { get; set; }
    public string director { get; set; }
    public string music_director { get; set; }
    public string release_date { get; set; }
    public string tags { get; set; }
    public string age_restriction { get; set; }
    public string box_office { get; set; }
    public string official_site { get; set; }
    public string duration { get; set; }
    public string writers { get; set; }
    public int imdb { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
    public string created { get; set; }
    public string modified { get; set; }
    public string movie_category_id { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
    public string movie_show_time_id { get; set; }
    public string theatre_movie_screen_id { get; set; }
    public string videous { get; set; }
    public string videos { get; set; }
    public string comming_soon { get; set; }
    public string avg { get; set; }
}

 public class MovieDetails
{
    public List<MovieDetail> movieDetaillist { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use a `TaskCompletionSource` in `GetMovieDetailsList`?

I'd do it like this:

```
public async Task<List<MovieDetail>> GetMovieDetailsList(int movieId)
{   
        string jsonresult = await WCFRESTServiceCall("GET", "movie_details");    
        var list = jsonresult.Deserialize<MovieDetails>();
        return list.movieDetaillist;
}
```

Your `searchMovies` method can look like this:

```
public async Task<List<MovieDetail>> searchMovies(string movietitle)
{
        List <MovieDetail> _myMovie = await GetMovieDetailsList(1);
        var list = _myMovie.Where(p => p.name == movietitle).ToList();    
        return list;
}
```

`await` the time expensive things. It doesn't matter *how* you got the list. You forget about that the list was built in a task after you get it. You can query it just like you do it with every other list.

Comment: thanks that worked I am just getting used to making web service calls so that was the example i came across

Comment: with the linq how would I build a query of optional where cluases can i do that with linq ?

Comment: That's a new question. You should read some Linq tutorials or at least http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101540/linq-or-equivalent-of-where

Answer (score 0):

In your, after the first awaited call, you have the result, so you can do

```
public Task<List<MovieDetail>> searchMovies(string movietitle)
{
        List <MovieDetail> _myMovie = await GetMovieDetailsList(1);
        var list = await Task.Run(() => how do i query above here ???? >());


        List<MovieDetail> _mySearchDetail = _myMovie.Where(p => p.name == movietitle).ToList();
            return await tcs.Task;
}


_myMovie.Where(x => x.Name == "title");
```

Or any property you want to search with