# C# - How to do multiple contains filters on an object list

Tags: c#, linq, filter, datatable, contains

I have a data table that I am trying to implement server side filtering on for the columns.  I am allowing multiple strings to query per column, and am trying to determine the best way to step through all the filters.  Below is an example of the table object, with just 2 of parameters for simplicity sake.

```
//table models from db
public class Parts
{
    public string PartName { get; set; }
    public virtual Series Series { get; set; }
}

public class Series
{
    public string SeriesName { get; set; }
}

//This is what is passed in from the datatable filter query
public class PartsTable
{
    public string PartName { get; set; }

    public string SeriesName { get; set; }
}


public IEnumerable<Parts> PartsTableSearch(PartsTable table)
{
    //Queries come in as comma separated string
    var partNameList = table.PartName?.Split(',');
    var seriesNameList = table.SeriesName?.Split(',');

    //Gets and generates the list of Parts
    var fullList = GetParts();

    if (partNameList != null && partNameList.Length > 0)
    {        
        foreach (var partName in partNameList)
        {
            fullList = fullList.Where(p => p.PartName.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower()));
        }
    }
    if (seriesNameList != null && seriesNameList.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (var seriesName in seriesNameList)
        {
            fullList = fullList.Where(p => p.Series.SeriesName.ToLower().Contains(seriesName.ToLower()));
        }
    }

    return fullList;
}
```

This won't work for what I want because for each parameter (ie. PartName) I need to be able to return all of the objects that have a PartName that contains the search strings in partNameList, then from that result, filter further on the SeriesNames that contain the search strings in seriesNameList, then return the resulting set.  However, the query for partNameList may be blank and only searching on seriesName, and vice versa.  Any suggestions?  I feel like it is an obvious answer that I am simply overlooking, although anything else I've searched for only works for a single query filter.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you to look into the `PredicateBuilder` class, more info inside [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2101561/3670737).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up getting it working.

```
var fullList = GetParts();        
if (partNameList != null && partNameList.Length > 0)
        {
            var tempList = new List<Parts>();
            foreach (var partName in partNameList)
            {
                tempList.AddRange(fullList.Where(p => p.PartName.ToLower().Contains(partName.ToLower().Trim())));
            }
            fullList = tempList;
        }
        if (seriesNameList != null && seriesNameList.Length > 0)
        {
            var tempList = new List<Parts>();
            foreach (var seriesName in seriesNameList)
            {
                tempList.AddRange(fullList.Where(p => p.Series.SeriesName.ToLower().Contains(seriesName.ToLower().Trim())).ToList());
            }
            fullList = tempList;
        }
return fullList.ToList();
```

Answer (score 6):

This can be done using a single `.Where` in 2 ways:

**Using `.Contain()`** which will return the exact match:

```
public IEnumerable<Parts> PartsTableSearch(PartsTable table)
{
    //Queries come in as comma separated string
    var partNameList = table.PartName?.Split(',');
    var seriesNameList = table.SeriesName?.Split(',');

    //Gets and generates the list of Parts
    var fullList = GetParts()
        .Where(p => partNameList.Contains(p.PartName.ToLower())
            || seriesNameList.Contains(p.Series.SeriesName.ToLower()))
        .ToList();

    return fullList;
}
```

**Using `.Any()`** which will return a partial match:

```
public IEnumerable<Parts> PartsTableSearch(PartsTable table)
{
    //Queries come in as comma separated string
    var partNameList = table.PartName?.Split(',');
    var seriesNameList = table.SeriesName?.Split(',');

    //Gets and generates the list of Parts
    var fullList = GetParts()
        .Where(p => partNameList.Any(n => n.Contains(p.PartName.ToLower())))
            || seriesNameList.Any(n => n.Contains(p.Series.SeriesName.ToLower())))
        .ToList();

    return fullList;
}
```

Comment: True. The `.Contains` will search for the for the exact value. However `.Any` will return a partial match. Revised my answer.

Comment: The lists.Any() are reversed for what I need in this example.  The partNameList is the query of partial strings, and the p.PartName is the name from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Made this for LinqToSql.  I've been told it won't work with Entity Framework.  It should work with an in-memory collection.

```
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> OrTheseFiltersTogether<T>(
        this IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> filters)
    {
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> firstFilter = filters.FirstOrDefault();
        if (firstFilter == null)
        {
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> alwaysTrue = x => true;
            return alwaysTrue;
        }

        var body = firstFilter.Body;
        var param = firstFilter.Parameters.ToArray();
        foreach (var nextFilter in filters.Skip(1))
        {
            var nextBody = Expression.Invoke(nextFilter, param);
            body = Expression.OrElse(body, nextBody);
        }
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> result = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
        return result;
    }
```

Called like so:

```
public IEnumerable<Parts> PartsTableSearch(PartsTable table)
{
    var fullList = GetParts();
    var filters = new List<Expression<Func<Part, bool>>>();

    if (table.PartName != null)
    {
        var partNameList = table.PartName.ToLower().Split(',');
        foreach (var partName in partNameList)
        {
            filters.Add(p => p.PartName.ToLower().Contains(partName));
        }
    }
    if (table.SeriesName != null)
    {
        var seriesNameList = table.SeriesName.ToLower().Split(',');
        foreach (var seriesName in seriesNameList)
        {
            filters.Add(p => p.Series.SeriesName.ToLower().Contains(seriesName));
        }
    }

    Expression<Func<Part, bool>> filter = filters.OrTheseFiltersTogether();

    return fullList.Where(filter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Yield return` with each result set you're getting from different queries. Doesn't matter if it's null all results will be collected in `IEnumerable<Parts>`.

```
public IEnumerable<Parts> PartsTableSearch(PartsTable table)
{
    //Queries come in as comma separated string
    var partNameList = table.PartName?.Split(',');
    var seriesNameList = table.SeriesName?.Split(',');

    //Gets and generates the list of Parts
    var fullList = GetParts();

    if (partNameList != null && partNameList.Length > 0)
    {        
        foreach (var partName in partNameList)
        {
            yield return fullList.Where(p => p.PartName.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower()));
        }
    }
    if (seriesNameList != null && seriesNameList.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (var seriesName in seriesNameList)
        {
            yield return fullList.Where(p => p.Series.SeriesName.ToLower().Contains(seriesName.ToLower()));
        }
    }

  yield return null;
}
```