# Using LINQ to get a list of items where the item contains a part of an item from another list

Tags: c#, linq

Having a list of models:

```
List<string> models = new List<string>
{
    "abcd1234",
    "xycd9999",
    "zzz999z",
    "ros7777"
};
```

Having a filterer list:

```
List<string> filterer = new List<string>
    {
        "cd",
        "9999"
    };
```

I am trying using LINQ to get all the models that contains as part of their name the filterer items.

**For this example:**

1. "abcd1234" and "xycd9999" contains "cd"
2. "xycd9999" contains "9999"

therefore the LINQ operation will return a list of the two items: "abcd1234" and "xycd9999".

```
var filteredList = models
                   .Where(m => m.Contains("/*HERE WILL BE THE FILTERER ITEMS*/"))
                   .Distinct()
                   .ToList();
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var filteredList = models
    .Where(x => filterer.Any(y => x.Contains(y))
    .ToList();
```

`Distinct` serves no purpose here, as the `Where` call doesn't introduce duplicates (unless of course `models` has duplicate values, and you want to remove those duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

["Or" equivalent in Linq Where() lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101540/or-equivalent-in-linq-where-lambda-expression)

Try to use PredicateBuilder as the link goes:

```
public static class PredicateBuilder
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T> ()  { return f => true;  }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T> () { return f => false; }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                      Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
           (Expression.OrElse (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                  Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
           (Expression.AndAlso (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }
}
```

In your case:

```
List<string> models = new List<string>
{
    "abcd1234",
    "xycd9999",
    "zzz999z",
    "ros7777"
};
List<string> filterer = new List<string>
{
    "cd",
    "9999"
};
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<string>();

foreach (string filter in filterer)
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(f => f.Contains(filter));
}

var filteredList = models.AsQueryable().Where(predicate).ToList();
```

Comment: I can think of two reasons to use the `PredicateBuilder` -- 1) the query is being run against an a provider which doesn't support mappings from `Contains` and `Any`; or 2) each string might follow its own logic branch (e.g. don't apply any clause with a null or empty string; apply a different predicate for numeric strings). But in this case the query is on an in-memory collection, and the filter clause is always the same, so I fail to see the benefit of using `PredicateBuilder` here,

Comment: yup for the mentioned scenario predicatebuilder is not needed, just another alternative in case for other purpose.