# ld: framework not found Flutter

Tags: flutter

When I build flutter project for iOS on iOS simulator, it gives me an error

```
ld: framework not found Flutter
```

and the build fails.

This is the error message when I try to build flutter project from xcode:

```
 export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0
 export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang \
     -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk \
     -L/Users/abhijeetnigoskar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-axtptzubiqvjnbhgcbxfykotbmup/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator \
     -L/Users/abhijeetnigoskar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-axtptzubiqvjnbhgcbxfykotbmup/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Stripe \
     -L/Users/abhijeetnigoskar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-axtptzubiqvjnbhgcbxfykotbmup/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared_preferences \
     -L/Users/abhijeetnigoskar/Desktop/flutter_workspace/zenspace_pro/ios/Pods/Stripe/InternalFrameworks \
     -L/Users/abhijeetnigoskar/Desktop/flutter_workspace/zenspace_pro/ios/Flutter \
     -F/Users/abhijeetnigoskar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-axtptzubiqvjnbhgcbxfykotbmup/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator \
     -F/Users/abhijeetnigoskar/Desktop/flutter_workspace/zenspace_pro/ios/Pods/../.symlinks/flutter/ios \
     -F/Users/abhijeetnigoskar/Desktop/flutter_workspace/zenspace_pro/ios/Flutter \
     -filelist /Users/abhijeetnigoskar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-axtptzubiqvjnbhgcbxfykotbmup/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner.LinkFileList \
     -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks \
     -mios-simulator-version-min=9.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto \
     -Xlinker /Users/abhijeetnigoskar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-axtptzubiqvjnbhgcbxfykotbmup/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner_lto.o \
     -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate \
     -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc \
     -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lStripe -lStripe3DS2 -lshared_preferences \
     -framework Contacts -framework CoreLocation -framework Flutter \
     -framework Foundation -framework PassKit -framework Security \
     -framework WebKit -ObjC -lStripe -lStripe3DS2 -lshared_preferences \
     -framework Contacts -framework CoreLocation -framework Flutter \
     -framework Foundation -framework PassKit -framework Security \
     -framework WebKit -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements \
     -Xlinker /Users/abhijeetnigoskar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-axtptzubiqvjnbhgcbxfykotbmup/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Runner.app-Simulated.xcent \
     -framework App -framework Flutter -lPods-Runner -Xlinker -dependency_info \
     -Xlinker /Users/abhijeetnigoskar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-axtptzubiqvjnbhgcbxfykotbmup/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner_dependency_info.dat \
     -o /Users/abhijeetnigoskar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-axtptzubiqvjnbhgcbxfykotbmup/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Runner

ld: framework not found Flutter
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is the output when i build flutter project from VScode using the command `flutter build ios --debug  --verbose`:

```
-framework Flutter -lPods-Runner -Xlinker -dependency_info \
-Xlinker /Users/abhijeetnigoskar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-axtptzubiqvjnbhgcbxfykotbmup/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Runner_dependency_info.dat \
-o /Users/abhijeetnigoskar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-axtptzubiqvjnbhgcbxfykotbmup/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Runner

 ld: framework not found Flutter
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

 [+1864 ms] "flutter ios" took 46,343ms.
 [        ] "flutter ios" took 46,343ms.
 Encountered error while building for device.

 #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28:3)
 #1      BuildIOSCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_ios.dart:94:7) <asynchronous suspension>
 #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:478:18) <asynchronous suspension>
 #3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:383:33) <asynchronous suspension>
 #4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:29) <asynchronous suspension>
 #5      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
 #6      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
 #7      _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
 #8      runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
 #9      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:152:18) <asynchronous suspension>
 #10     FlutterCommand.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:375:20)
 #11     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:27) <asynchronous suspension>
 #12     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:396:21) |asynchronous suspension>
 #13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:29) <asynchronous suspension>
 #14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
 #15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
 #16     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
 #17     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
 #18     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:152:18) <asynchronous suspension>
 #19     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:356:19) <asynchronous suspension>
 #20     CommandRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:args/command_runner.dart:112:25)
 #21     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:224:31)
 #22     CommandRunner.run (package:args/command_runner.dart:112:14)
 #23     FlutterCommandRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:242:18)
 #24     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:22) <asynchronous suspension>
 #25     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
 #26     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
 #27     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
 #28     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1500:12)
 #29     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:60:18) <asynchronous suspension>
 #30     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:29) <asynchronous suspension>
 #31     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
 #32     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
 #33     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
 #34     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
 #35     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:152:18) <asynchronous suspension>
 #36     runInContext enter code here(package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:56:24) <asynchronous suspension>
 #37     run (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:51:10)
 #38     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:62:9) <asynchronous suspension>
 #39     main (file:///Users/abhijeetnigoskar/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:8:3)
 #40 _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32)
 #41 RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
```

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101540/or-equivalent-in-linq-where-lambda-expression to know how to ask question

Answer (score 18):

I had tried many solutions to this error.
Only possible solution is to delete the flutter folder at the FLUTTER PATH, and recopy the flutter folder.

This solved my error.

Comment: Thanks man. I've been doing the: clean up this, delete this, things 3 days already. Flutter clean, flutter upgrade, pod install, pod disintegrate, clean built folder, delete some path. None of them worked. This was the only solution! Cheers.

Comment: recopy from where?

Comment: @Mikki you can recopy to the same path, it works thanks Anivesh Readdy

Comment: Only solution that worked, sad this bug isn't fixed yet!

Comment: FLUTTER PATH , is sdk path .... just download new sdk and replace old sdk folder ( flutter ) with newly downloaded sdk(flutter).

Comment: Instead of delete the folder, it was enough rename the "flutter" folder and rename to the original name again.

Comment: This worked for me. Delete your flutter folder on your computer. Download and save the new flutter folder to wherever you had it before... copy/paste or drag/drop the new flutter folder to the same location where your original flutter folder was before you deleted it.

Comment: yes, this will solve the issue, but why that happened ?

Comment: Thanks for this, looks like XCode maintains a symlink. I accidentally deleted  one of flutter while tidying up space on my mac.

Answer (score 14):

the error reason was that I deleted the flutter command line from Documents folder. but it's solved by running `flutter upgrade`

Comment: In my case, it helps.

Answer (score 4):

Just need to delete flutter folder and then you can put flutter folder to the same path and **extract latest flutter zip** and restart system,it will work..

Answer (score 1):

**Problem can be solved without installing whole package**

I mistakenly deleted `Flutter.runner` file from the framework directory. It started showing this error while building a release. Then I did following steps instead of installing all package

1. Removed `myproject/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework` folder
2. In iOS directory run `pod install` (You can try, delete all pod configuration and install again)

What might be happening? For some developers they are re-installing flutter package and then problem is going away, basically here in my case I would like to add that by loosing `flutter.runner` file of your project you are removing your iOS configuration of flutter app. Flutter commands are not working so solution has worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I got this error after deleting the flutter instances while trying to clean up some storage on my 258go macbook to update Xcode :(, in doing so I probably deleted the flutter.framework.

The solutions given here have not changed anything for me.

So I tried to clean up everything in the pod, including the cache. The `pod install` command failed because it missed the ios tools, which can be downloaded with `flutter precache --ios`.

So the complete process to solve this problem for me was :

```sh
cd ios
pod cache clean --all
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
pod deintegrate
flutter precache --ios
pod install
```

I hope that this solution will help someone and prevent them from losing a whole day's work as it did for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the Flutter to add it in its **PATH**

Navigate to the flutter package, take the folder path and add it to the path which should look like.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/package_to_flutter/bin
```

Additionally, format your question so that its easier for people to answer quickly.

Cheers

Comment: I successfully compile and build for android. But when i going to compile and build for ios then shows me error "framework not found Flutter". So may be this is not a path issue.
Please have a look on it.

Output of command "echo $PATH" :-
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/abhijeetnigoskar/android-sdks/platform-tools/:/Users/abhijeetnigoskar/android-sdks/tools/:/Users/abhijeetnigoskar/flutter/bin

Comment: Seems to be some type of dependency issue with flutter. Try running

`flutter channel master`
 followed by

`flutter upgrade`

Then try re-running the build.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing CocoaPod from your project

```
cd ios
pod deintegrate
flutter clean
flutter run
```

If this doesn't work try reinstalling flutter

Answer (score 0):

I personally tried everything I saw on forums, but what worked for me was deleting the flutter SDK and downloading it again and then running. It worked for me, it is possible something else might work for you.
The problem was basically the project was running fine two days ago, then maybe something happened with flutter upgrade downgrade stuff etc that I might have done, which seems to be something that might have introduced this problem. But overall

Summary: deleting flutter SDK and downloading new worked for me

Answer (score 0):

deleting flutter SDK folder and download it again

```
flutter upgrade
flutter pub get
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try all, but still not work!

- 1,download flutter again.
- 2,unzip flutter
- 3,replace your flutter folder.(backup flutter folder before replace )
- 4,restart your Mac
- 5,run your project on xcode!

Answer (score 0):

Delete the old flutter folder (Don't forget to take a copy of it). Download new flutter it will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I Got this issue while Building an Archive for a Project. (Release for iOS)
I was cleaning my Mac and
accidentally deleted the flutter framework that was the issue.
its Simple Solution is to run

```
flutter upgrade
```

Restart the System then

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
pod install
```

Everything work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I also facing the same issue in macOS 12.5, using the flutter clean command fix this problem:

```
~/fvm/versions/2.10.3/bin/flutter clean
```

Answer (score -11):

This worked for me.

Delete your `ios` folder in your project, then run again.