# framework not found in webview_flutter when making build in IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, webview-flutter

I used the webview_flutter package to show some pages in webview in a flutter, In android, it's working fine but when I try to run in IOS I get an error as in the screenshot.

Can anyone help, I really stuck here.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried flutter clean and then rebuilding?

Comment: Yes I tried it but no luck

Comment: Are any of these suggestions helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57557026/ld-framework-not-found-flutter

Comment: I already tried it, but no way

Comment: I'm not sure what else to try then, especially without more information.

Comment: facing the same issue

Answer (score -1):

Delete flutter folder on your PC. Download a new flutter SDK and then copy it your Flutter Path (instead of deleted flutter folder).

Answer (score -1):

[image]

After trying a lot , I found solution

1. Open **Runner.xcworkspace** in Xcode
2. select runner
3. select **build setting**
4. search for **Other linker flag**
5. inside debug and release (select runner section)
6. replace "webview_flutter" to "webview_flutter_wkwebview"

That's all.
Everything work fine.