# How can solve this issues ? Framework not found Flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I can not Suddenly　build Ios.
I try to use this site but It doesn't clear.

https://www.mechengjp.com/%E3%80%90flutter%E3%80%91xcode%E3%81%A7%E3%83%93%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89%E4%B8%AD%E3%81%AB/

please tell how to solve this issues.

If I had to guess, I deleted the documents that were in my Mac storage.
That may have something to do with it.

## Error message

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/zd/z67lws4n4q91pwcryc28v10c0000gn/T/flutter_tools.CmNt1I/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirYUeqQq/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    ld: framework not found Flutter
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.6, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'permission_handler_apple' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'url_launcher_ios' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'shared_preferences_ios' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'path_provider_ios' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.6, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'location' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'GoogleDataTransport' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'GTMSessionFetcher' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'Libuv-gRPC' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Libuv-gRPC' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Runner.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'image_picker_ios' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'cloud_firestore' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'Firebase' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreInternal' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'flutter_native_splash' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'google_maps_flutter_ios' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.6, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'app_settings' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'firebase_auth' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'FirebaseStorage' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'FirebaseCore' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'GoogleMaps' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'FirebaseAuthInterop' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.6, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'Pods-Runner' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'firebase_core' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'FirebaseAppCheckInterop' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'FirebaseFirestore' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'PromisesObjC' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'camera_avfoundation' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'FirebaseAuth' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'firebase_storage' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.6, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'geocoding' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'sqflite' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreExtension' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'FirebaseStorageInternal' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/isekiryuutarou/Veroo/veroo_web3_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp' from project 'Pods')

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/zd/z67lws4n4q91pwcryc28v10c0000gn/T/flutter_tools.CmNt1I/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirYUeqQq/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Error (Xcode): Framework not found Flutter

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14.
```

## Flutter Doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.2, on macOS 13.0.1 22A400 darwin-arm, locale ja-JP)
    • Flutter version 3.0.2 at /Users/isekiryuutarou/fvm/versions/3.0.2
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision cd41fdd495 (6 months ago), 2022-06-08 09:52:13 -0700
    • Engine revision f15f824b57
    • Dart version 2.17.3
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/isekiryuutarou/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.0.1 22A400 darwin-arm
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 107.0.5304.121

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

## What we tried

・flutter clean

・Delete pod file.lock

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the flutter SDK folder, and copying it again, following this guide: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos
As described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62830644/13328624

Comment: Thank you so much for answering.

I tried deleting and reinserting the Flutter SDK folder with what you told me and then building it, but it didn't work.