# Entity Framework Linq Query using multiple where

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, filter

Does the multiple .Where() act as an AND (&&) or act as Or (||)  for example:

```
 var db = new myContext();
 var query = db.User.Where(u => u.Gender == "Male");
 query = query.Where(u => u.IsActive == true);
```

Is it equivalent to :

```
   Select *
   from user
   where gender = 'Male' 
     and IsActive = true;
```

Comment: As per site rules you should do some research and show what you TRIED. Did you try?

Comment: Yes I did and I found it's act as and but no answer clarify it @TomTom

Comment: so what Then act is it act as And or Or operator @ah

Comment: No, it obviously add as AND. Multiple Where clauses are further limiting. Anything else would be illogical. First where output is running into second where.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the result of one filter through another, so logically they will act like an "and".

Say you have a deck of cards. You then use a "filter" that only gives you red cards. You then want to pass the result to another filter that only gives you sevens.

So effectively you get cards that are red AND have a value of seven.

> Is there a way to change this behavior and make it act as 'or'?

No, there's not a way to take a query that has a `Where` clause and "append" a second `Where` clause that acts like an `or`.

If you're trying  to dynamically append filters with an "or" operation, the most direct way is to combine the two predicates with an "or" (see ["Or" equivalent in Linq Where() lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101540))

One other way would be to re-use the original query, use two *separate* `Where` queries, and `Union` the results.

```
var result1 = a.Where(u => u.Gender == "Male");
var result2 = a.Where(u => u.IsActive == true);

var result = result1.Union(result2);
```

But there may be performance concerns with this sort of "indirect" OR clause

Comment: Is there a way to change this  behavior and make it act as 'or'. The purpose of this is to use a query builder or dynamic query? @D Stanley

Answer (score 0):

Just use `&&` operator:

```
var query = db.User.Where(u => u.Gender == "Male" && u.IsActive == true);
```

The `&&` operator means `and`. That the above condition can be read like *get all users with gender=="Male" and isActive=="true"*