# dynamically varied number of conditions in the 'where' statement using LINQ

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, where-clause

I'm working on my first project using LINQ (in mvc), so there is probably something very simple that I missed. However, a day of searching and experimenting has not turned up anything that works, hence the post.

I'm trying to write a LINQ query (Linq to SQL) that will contain a multiple number of conditions in the where statement separated by an OR or an AND. We don't know how many conditions are going to be in the query until runtime. This is for a search filter control, where the user can select multiple criteria to filter by.

```
select * from table
where table.col = 1 
    OR table.col = 2
    OR table.col = 7
    .... 'number of other conditions
```

Before I would just construct the SQL query as a string while looping over all conditions. However, it seems like there should be a nice way of doing this in LINQ. 
I have tried looking using expression trees, but they seem a bit over my head for the moment. Another idea was to execute a lambda function inside the where statement, like so:

```
For Each value In values
    matchingRows = matchingRows.Where(Function(row) row.col = value)
```

However, this only works for AND conditions. How do I do ORs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) for this. It makes dynamic WHERE clauses very easy.

Answer (score 1):

`AND` is easy - you can just call `Where` in a loop. `OR` is much trickier. You mention SQL, so I'm assuming this is something like LINQ-to-SQL, in which case one way I've found to do this involves building custom `Expression` trees at runtime - [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930677/extend-iqueryablet-where-as-or-instead-of-and-relationship) (the example is C#, but let me know if you need help translating it to VB; my VB isn't fantastic any more, so I'll let you try first... you can probably read C# better than I can write VB).

Unfortunately, this won't work with EF in 3.5SP1 (due to the `Expression.Invoke`), but I *believe* this is fixed in 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (forgive my VB):

```
Expression(Of Func(Of Something, Boolean)) filter = Nothing
ParameterExpression rowParam = Expression.Parameter("row", CType(Something))

For Each value In values
    filterPart = Expression.Equal( _
        Expression.Property(rowParam, "col"), _
        Expression.Constant(value)))
    If filter Is Nothing Then
        filter = filterPart 
    Else
        filter = Expression.OrElse(filter, filterPart)
    End If
Next

If newPredicate IsNot Nothing Then
    matchingRows = matchingRows.Where( _
        Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of SomeType, Boolean))(filter, rowParam))
End If
```

No guarantees, however, my VB is a little rusty :-)

But [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) might be a better solution if you want to do more complicated stuff than just `And`s and `Or`s.