# Filtering IQueryable is bringing back wrong results

Tags: c#, iqueryable

I have method which accepts `IQueryable<T>` as a parameter called `attachments`. Inside this method I filter the query further in multiple `if` statements. So my code is as follows:

```
if(firstCondition)
{
   attachments = attachments.Where(i => i.TestItemId == 1); //3 records in db
   DoWork(attachments);
}
if(secondCondition)
{
   attachments = attachments.Where(i => i.TestItemId == 2); //2 records in db
   DoWork(attachments);
}
...
```

Inside `DoWork();`I do:

```
foreach(var items in attachments)
{
   //write attachment name to file here
}
```

In the database I have a total of 5 records which inside the first `if` statement I get the appropriate results back. However in the second `if` condition I get 0 result back in the query. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong please.

Please note both of the if conditions will be true.

Comment: Concatenating `Where` conditions results in an `AND` query. So effectively the two combined result in `SELECT * FROM attachments WHERE TestItemId = 1 AND TestItemId = 2`. Perhaps you were thinking of an `OR`

Comment: @Silvermind What would you suggest the approach I take? Will I have a create a `var` in every if condition

Comment: Are you wanting to have OR logic on your conditions? ie Id is 1 or 2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extend IQueryable<T> Where() as OR instead of AND relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930677/extend-iqueryablet-where-as-or-instead-of-and-relationship)

Comment: @Chris Inside first if I only want items with Id 1 and inside second if with Id 2 and so not. I have a total of 8 conditions to meet

Comment: @Code: So they are completely independent things? In that case dont' reassign `attachments`. Better still put each of your conditions in their own method and pass `attachment` in to them and then you will be hard pressed to repeat this behaviour. Your problem seems to be that by the second condition you are working on the already reduced set of items in attachment because of the assignment. The other option is putting your where clause inline with the DoWork call.

Comment: @Chris Yes they're complete independent things. Can you provide an example please

Answer (score 4):

You shoudn't assign attachments for the firstCondition, result will be filter by 2 conditions:
TestItemId == 1 && TestItemId == 2. 
=> It always return empty list;

Answer (score 3):

## Concatenation of conditions

The problem is with the assignation, causing a concatenation of the `Where` clausules.

```
attachments = attachments.Where(i => i.TestItemId == 1);
attachments = attachments.Where(i => i.TestItemId == 2);
```

The following code is the same as the above:

```
attachments.Where(i => i.TestItemId == 1).Where(i => i.TestItemId == 2);
```

If you remove the `attachments =` from both ifs you won't have any problem.

```
if(firstCondition)
{
   DoWork(attachments.Where(i => i.TestItemId == 1));
}

if(secondCondition)
{
   DoWork(attachments.Where(i => i.TestItemId == 2));
}
```

Comment: The downside of your last block of code is it is now doing multiple SQL queries.

Comment: Before it was doing multiple SQLs. You need to use ToList before to avoid that. But I don't know what kind of Object is `attachments`, it can be a List converted into an IQueryable.

Comment: I know, I'm just saying that the entire thing could have been done with a single call.

Comment: `attachment`is `IQueryable<AllAttachments>`